# One of my variables seems to not be working which I'm having trouble finding

Tags: python, python-2.7, variables

I am doing the learn python the hard way course and I had to make my own little story using python. I did make it and I spent a lot of time fixing its many problems, but there is one variable which has resulted in many errors for me.

Here is my code:

```
def party():
print "You are at a friend's house, and there you find three men who disrespect you.\
\nDo you fight them, insult back, or do you invite them for a drink?"
party_answer = raw_input()
while (party_answer != "fight") and (party_answer != "insult") and (party_answer != "drink"):
    print "Type either 'fight', 'insult', or 'drink'"
    party_answer = raw_input()  

if party_answer == "fight":
    fight()
elif party_answer == "insult":
    insult()
elif party_answer == "drink":
    drink()


def fight():
    print """You decide to fight the men.
After a while, the men start pleading for mercy.
Do you hit them more?"""
fight_answer = raw_input()
while (fight_answer != "yes") and (fight_answer != "no"):
    print "Type either 'yes' or 'no'"
    fight_answer = raw_input()

if fight_answer == "yes":
    print """Your friend sees you fighting and asks you why
Do you blame them, or do you take responsibility and apologize?"""
    fight_answer_y = raw_input()
    while (fight_answer_y != "blame them") and (fight_answer_y != "apologize"):
        print "Type either 'blame them' or 'apologize'"
        fight_answer_y = raw_input()

    if fight_answer_y == "blame them":
        print """Your friend is angry at you fighting at all, and does not believe \
that they started the fight. He kicks you out of the party."""
        exit(1)
    elif fight_answer_y == "apologize":
        print "Your friend forgives you, and asks you to drink with him."
        exit(2)

elif fight_answer == "no":
    print """The men take advantage of you forgiveness and start hitting you.
Fortunately, your friend arrives at this moment. He see them hitting you, \
and then kicks them out of the party."""
    exit(2)

def insult():
print """You insult them, and they challenge you to a fight.
Do you fight them or tell your friend?"""
insult_answer = raw_input()
while (insult_answer != "fight") and (insult_answer != "tell friend"):
    print "Type either 'fight' or 'tell friend'"
    insult_answer = raw_input()

if insult_answer == "fight":
    fight()
elif insult_answer == "tell friend":
    print """You decide to tell your friend.
He says he is happy you told him, and invites you for a drink
The men get kicked out"""
    exit(2)

def drink():
print """You tell them that you will buy drinks for them,\
and they rudely ask you why you are doing this.
Do you insult them or give them a polite response?"""
drink_answer = raw_input()
while (drink_answer != "insult") and (drink_answer != "polite response"):
    print "Type either 'insult' or 'polite response'"
    drink_answer = raw_input()

if drink_answer == "insult":
    insult()
elif drink_answer == "polite response":
    print "You politely respond to them, and they sit down with you and apologize."
    exit(2)

def exit(x):
if x == 1:
    print "You lost. Better luck next time!"
    again = raw_input("Do you want to try again?: ")
    while (again != "yes") and (again != "no"):
        print "Type either 'yes' or 'no'"
        again = raw_input("Do you want to try again?: ")

    if again == "yes":
        party()
    elif again == "no":
        quit()

elif x == 2:
    print "You won. Good job!"
    again = raw_input("Do you want to try again?: ")
    while (again != "yes") and (again != "no"):
        print "Type either 'yes' or 'no'"
        again = raw_input("Do you want to try again?: ")

    if again == "yes":
        party()
    elif again == "no":
        quit() 

party()
```

I seem to be getting an error in regards to the variable "fight_answer_y"
Here is the error I'm getting:

```
  File "mygame1.py", line 38, in fight
    elif fight_answer_y == "apologize":
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'fight_answer_y' referenced before assignment
```

Can anyone help explain this since I am new to Python.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Your indentation looks wrong in several places; please fix it up to match what you actually have. The use of `fight_answer_y` appears correct, but if the indentation is even a little off, it could easily break the way you describe.

Comment: Here is a better look at my code: http://paste.ofcode.org/Lby8kqUghyhmKyms2QMP9C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: Always configure your editor to expand tabs to four spaces, per [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation), don't just have it display tabs as four spaces because it hides issues with mixing tabs and spaces.

Explanation: In [your paste](http://paste.ofcode.org/Lby8kqUghyhmKyms2QMP9C), the problem is that an `elif` and the associated block is indented too shallowly, attaching to an outer `if` instead of the inner `if` it's supposed to attach to. The problem is because you're mixing spaces and tabs, `if fight_answer_y == "blame them":` is indented with two tabs, while `elif fight_answer_y == "apologize":` is indented with eight spaces. You're probably using an editor that displays tabs as four spaces (Stack Overflow does this too), so they appear at the same alignment, but Python 2 always treats a tab as being equivalent to eight spaces, so the code that looks like:

```
if fight_answer == "yes":
    print """Your friend sees you fighting and asks you why
Do you blame them, or do you take responsibility and apologize?"""
    fight_answer_y = raw_input()
    while (fight_answer_y != "blame them") and (fight_answer_y != "apologize"):
        print "Type either 'blame them' or 'apologize'"
        fight_answer_y = raw_input()

    if fight_answer_y == "blame them":
        print """Your friend is angry at you fighting at all, and does not believe \
that they started the fight. He kicks you out of the party."""
        exit(1)
    elif fight_answer_y == "apologize": # <-- ***LOOKS LIKE ATTACHED TO if fight_answer_y == "blame them":***
        print "Your friend forgives you, and asks you to drink with him."
        exit(2)

elif fight_answer == "no":
    print """The men take advantage of you forgiveness and start hitting you.
```

thanks to your editor displaying tabs as four space indents is being  interpreted as:

```
if fight_answer == "yes":
    print """Your friend sees you fighting and asks you why
Do you blame them, or do you take responsibility and apologize?"""
    fight_answer_y = raw_input()
    while (fight_answer_y != "blame them") and (fight_answer_y != "apologize"):
        print "Type either 'blame them' or 'apologize'"
        fight_answer_y = raw_input()

    if fight_answer_y == "blame them":
        print """Your friend is angry at you fighting at all, and does not believe \
that they started the fight. He kicks you out of the party."""
        exit(1)
elif fight_answer_y == "apologize": # <-- ***ACTUALLY ATTACHED TO if fight_answer == "yes":***
    print "Your friend forgives you, and asks you to drink with him."
    exit(2)

elif fight_answer == "no":
    print """The men take advantage of you forgiveness and start hitting you.
```

thanks to Python treating the same tabs as eight space indents. You got unlucky and the indentation appeared valid (most other failures like this mean SyntaxErrors, or cause code to drop out of method definitions so the failure is obvious). In this case, it means when `fight_answer` isn't `"yes"`, you try to test for `fight_answer_y == "apologize"`, except `fight_answer_y` is only defined in the `fight_answer == "yes"` case, meaning `fight_answer_y` is undefined.

If you had your editor configured to follow [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation) (expand tabs to spaces, use four space indents), the alignment issue would have been obvious. If you'd been running on Python 3, it's less tolerant of inconsistent use of tabs and spaces, and your code would have reported the problem with `TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation`. But as is, you had code that looked right, and ran wrong. Again: ***ALWAYS* use [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation) rules for whitespace** to avoid problems like this. Every editor out there (aside from Notepad) can be configured to expand tabs to spaces with four space indents; do it.

Answer (score 0):

Your indentation is wrong. This seems to work as far as I can tell.

```
def party():
    print "You are at a friend's house, and there you find three men who disrespect you.\
    \nDo you fight them, insult back, or do you invite them for a drink?"
    party_answer = raw_input()
    while (party_answer != "fight") and (party_answer != "insult") and (party_answer != "drink"):
        print "Type either 'fight', 'insult', or 'drink'"
        party_answer = raw_input()
    if party_answer == "fight":
        fight()
    elif party_answer == "insult":
        insult()
    elif party_answer == "drink":
        drink()


def fight():
    print """You decide to fight the men.
After a while, the men start pleading for mercy.
Do you hit them more?"""
    fight_answer = raw_input()
    while (fight_answer != "yes") and (fight_answer != "no"):
        print "Type either 'yes' or 'no'"
        fight_answer = raw_input()

    if fight_answer == "yes":
        print """Your friend sees you fighting and asks you why
Do you blame them, or do you take responsibility and apologize?"""
        fight_answer_y = raw_input()
        while (fight_answer_y != "blame them") and (fight_answer_y != "apologize"):
            print "Type either 'blame them' or 'apologize'"
            fight_answer_y = raw_input()

        if fight_answer_y == "blame them":
            print """Your friend is angry at you fighting at all, and does not believe \
that they started the fight. He kicks you out of the party."""
            exit(1)
        elif fight_answer_y == "apologize":
            print "Your friend forgives you, and asks you to drink with him."
            exit(2)

    elif fight_answer == "no":
        print """The men take advantage of you forgiveness and start hitting you.
Fortunately, your friend arrives at this moment. He see them hitting you, \
and then kicks them out of the party."""
        exit(2)

def insult():
    print """You insult them, and they challenge you to a fight.
    Do you fight them or tell your friend?"""
    insult_answer = raw_input()
    while (insult_answer != "fight") and (insult_answer != "tell friend"):
        print "Type either 'fight' or 'tell friend'"
        insult_answer = raw_input()

    if insult_answer == "fight":
        fight()
    elif insult_answer == "tell friend":
        print """You decide to tell your friend.
He says he is happy you told him, and invites you for a drink
The men get kicked out"""
        exit(2)

def drink():
    print """You tell them that you will buy drinks for them,\
and they rudely ask you why you are doing this.
Do you insult them or give them a polite response?"""
    drink_answer = raw_input()
    while (drink_answer != "insult") and (drink_answer != "polite response"):
        print "Type either 'insult' or 'polite response'"
        drink_answer = raw_input()

    if drink_answer == "insult":
        insult()
    elif drink_answer == "polite response":
        print "You politely respond to them, and they sit down with you and apologize."
        exit(2)

def exit(x):
    if x == 1:
        print "You lost. Better luck next time!"
        again = raw_input("Do you want to try again?: ")
        while (again != "yes") and (again != "no"):
            print "Type either 'yes' or 'no'"
            again = raw_input("Do you want to try again?: ")

        if again == "yes":
            party()
        elif again == "no":
            quit()

    elif x == 2:
        print "You won. Good job!"
        again = raw_input("Do you want to try again?: ")
        while (again != "yes") and (again != "no"):
            print "Type either 'yes' or 'no'"
            again = raw_input("Do you want to try again?: ")

        if again == "yes":
            party()
        elif again == "no":
            quit()

party()
```

Comment: Thanks! Can you tell me the exact part i got wrong because I spent hours looking through the code and I did not encounter any indentation mistakes. Here is a better look at my code: http://paste.ofcode.org/Lby8kqUghyhmKyms2QMP9C